# React in Typescript with Semantic: Displaying info in Semantic Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, semantic-ui-react

I have an array data sourcing from a JSON file and I need to display some names in the drop down. I am using Semantic UI Dropdown. How can I achieve this? I was able to get it functioning in react however after rewriting the code to include typescript I am unable to. New to react and typescript. In the `Dropdown` I have set up options to be `this.state.jockeys` but no data shows up but console.log(`this.state.jockeys`) shows me the data. When I click on the dropdown, an empty list  (with the right number of rows as my data length but the fields are empty) meaning somehow it's picking up my data but cant it somehow cant be read. How would I get the `value` and `key`. That could be the problem.

NB: I want to display `login` property in the dropdown.

Here's what I have;

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Divider, Container, Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import 'react-promise';
import { Jockey } from '../Jockey';
const data: JockeyArray[] = require('../../team.json');
import { getUniqueJockeys } from '../../utils/uniqueUtil';

interface Props {
    start: boolean;
    reset: boolean;
    startRandom: boolean;
}

interface JockeyArray {
    id: number;
    login: string;
    avatar_url: string;
}

interface State {
    nextRacers: string[];
    jockeys: JockeyArray[];
}

// Race Component
export class Race extends React.Component<Props, State> { 
    
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            jockeys: data as JockeyArray[], 
            nextRacers: [],
        };
    }

    handleChange = () => {
   
    }

    render() {
         const options = data.map(({ id, login }) => ({ key: id, value: login, text: login }));
        console.log(options);
            return (
                <div>
                    <Divider />
                    <div className="App-container">
                        <div className="App-dropdown">
                            <Container>
                                <p>Add jockeys to the race in the dropdown below (and click Start)</p>
                                <Dropdown 
                                    placeholder="Select Jockey..." 
                                    selection={true}
                                    search={true}
                                    value={}
                                    key={}
                                    options={options}
                                    onClick={this.handleChange}
                                />
                            </Container>
                        </div>  
                    </div> 
                </div>  
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Example JSON**

```js
[
  {
    "login": "alvinward",
      "id": 18378578,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.ttrs",
  },
  {
    "login": "meganswat",
      "id": 38345670,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.xxx",
  },
  {
    "login": "michaelflinch",
      "id": 48378108,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.xggj",
  },
]
```

Comment: What does you data look like? I haven't done Semantic UI but looking at the docs, it seems like it requires an array of objects

Comment: It just has the properties as listed in `JockeyArray` interface above. I passed the array in `options` or I thought did. Not sure if I did it correctly but using react only the data was displayed.

Comment: I see, I'm wondering about the `data as` you're using also

Comment: Added sample JSON to work with. I've managed to finally display the names using mapping function but I'm not able to use the key. Will need it for event handling

Comment: Try removing the key and value props in your dropdown component, it seems like you're not setting it to any value.